# What kind of coordinates are these numbers?

Tags: geolocation, shapefile, geo

I have geo data, that contain X field like: 1012532,749 and Y field like: 178774,7655. This data from the shapefile format, but I don`t know in what GEO standart this data is.

Maybe someone know, or can show me the way to find out, how translate this coords in GPS.

Comment: There is now way of knowing what kind of coordinate system this is from your description. A shape file can have an optional *prj* file, where the projection is defined. If you have such a file, look there, or post the content.  If not ask the source where you got that file from.

Comment: Yes i have a content of prj file  GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment the situation is clear:

You got an invalid shape file:

The prj file states WGS84 coordinates in decimal degrees
which has range: (longitude(x) [-180-.0,  180.0], latitude(y): [-90.0, 90.0].
But the coordinates posted are not in valid range.

The prj definition does not fit to the rest of the shape files (your posted coordinate).
(This happens because the prj file is optional, and has probably the default settings  of some other project)

There is little chance of knowing, without further knowlegde.
Simply ask the data provider which geographical datum  (name) the coordinates are related to. Further you should claim, that the file is erorrnous and that they should provide a correct prj file (or remove the prj file, if the coordinates are not related to world coordinates)

IF you know the source, e.g the swiss "Landesvermessung" then you could think it is for example a "Swiss Grid CH1903+ / LV95" grid system. (This was an example, the coordinates are not in that Swiss grid)
But it does not make sense to reverse engineer that, just ask the data provider, or if appliable read the info where you have got that data from.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i use QGIS to convert coordinates and then save to a server. For now it work.